Rear derailleur has vertical slack
Tried to fix an old bike with Shimano Acera 8-gear rear derailleur. The Derailleur felt somehow slack/limp, with vertical slack: what I mean by vertical slack is that when I turned the bicycle upside down, the derailleur arm "fell" on the cassette, or in other words it didn't stay fixed. I could lift it up from the derailleur cage. So I would like to know what causes this and is there a fix for it, or does the derailleur need to be changed?
Red arrow in photo shows the direction of the slack, when lifted from the cage.


This is going to need pictures, but if a the big spring is broken (as seems likely) you'll need to replace the whole derailleur.

Thanks, added a photo. The big spring looked like it was in one piece, and it also shifted up and down pretty normally. Wouldn't that require the spring to work?

Get a new RD, 8-speed ones are cheap.

The "P-spring" which gives the derailleur cage it's functionality to keep the chain taut and in alignment with chosen gear on the cassette, is broken or one of its ends has come out of its fixing hole (each end of the cylindrical spring are held captive, one within the body of the derailleur, the other in a hole in the derailleur cage. This allows the spring to wind and unwind bringing the proper motion and chain tension capability of the derailleur cage).  A third possibility is a broken or very worn cage stop found on the outside of the derailleur body. The stop is designed to prevent the derailleur cage from rotating past that point and unwinding all the spring tension required to function.
Only the situation where an end of the spring has become dislodged is in any way repairable. The other possibles I mention are fatal to the derailleur and replacement would be required. (Even then, it's sometimes the situation where that hole for the spring is worn such that it can't hold the end of the spring as it should.
A comparable replacement derailleur, Shimano Acera or Tourney, can cost as little as $15-20 USD.
